# Javascript Regular Expressions are not working; always returns false

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression that will check that the strings matches the format 'ACT' followed by 6 digits eg. 'ACT123456'

Though it looks quite simple, none of my options work; the function always returns false.

I tried the following combinations:
Pure regexpression literals

```
var format = /^ACT\d{6}$/;
var format = /^ACT[0-9]{6}$/;
```

Or using RegExp object with double escaping (eg. \\d) and with single escaping (\d)

```
var format = new RegExp("^ACT\\d{6}$");
var format = new RegExp("^ACT[0-9]{6}$");
```

My function for testing is:

```
 function testPattern(field, pattern) {
     if (!pattern.test(field)) {
         return false;} 
     else {
       return true;
    }}
```

Comment: What is the value of `field`?

Comment: This works? `testPattern("ACT123456", /^ACT\d{6}$/)`

Comment: Also what's the point of the `if-else` why not just use `pattern.test(field)`? Or `!!pattern.test(field)` if you want to make 100% sure, that the value has `Boolean` type?

Answer (score 0):

```
var format = /^ACT\d{6}$/;
```

works fine but the string must be `ACT123456` exactly with nothing preceding it or following it

eg `'ACT123456 '` fails

use

```
/ACT\d{6}/
```

to allow more tolerance  or strip the whitespace from the string first

Answer (score 0):

```
var testString = "ACT123456"; // string to test
// pattern as a regex literal
var pattern = /^ACT[0-9]{6}$/g; 

console.log(testString.match(pattern)); // output: ["ACT123456"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all guys for answers and feedback!

After being stuck with regular expressions, I realized that my problem with that I am not using field.value in my function.

So, the problem is with the function that must be:

```
function testPattern(field, pattern) {
 if (!pattern.test(field.value)) {
     return false;} 
 else {
   return true;
}}
```